How to disable navigation menu bar or swipe down gesture in Dialogs
In dialogs when I do swipe down gesture, a black bare appears over navigation menu and stays there.
Parent activity already has a navigation menu bar, and it behaves as it should. Dialog swipe down gestue overrides correct behaviour and makes the black menu bar stick.
fun showAboutUsDialog(){
    dialog?.dismiss() // Dismiss the current dialog, if any
    dialog = Dialog(this)
    dialog?.setContentView(R.layout.about_modal);

    // Check if dialog is not null before accessing it
    if (dialog != null) {
        val versionText : TextView = dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.version);
        val buttonOk : TextView = dialog!!.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);
        buttonOk.setOnClickListener{
            dialog!!.dismiss()
        }
        "${getString(R.string.version)} ${BuildConfig.VERSION_NAME}".also { versionText.text = it }
        dialog?.getWindow()?.setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        dialog!!.show();
    }
}

 I tried disabling navigation bar in dialgogs. Even though the flags are deprecated, navigation bar does not apper when I am in the dialog screen, but when I close the screen, the navigation bar reappears on the parent screen as a black bar and stays there.



 dialog?.window?.decorView?.apply {
        systemUiVisibility = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY or
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION or
                    SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
    }

Navigation bar that appears after entering dialog
